# C4D - Cloned objects containing fields that affect a deformer?

Tags: cinema-4d

I have a low poly sphere that makes up the ocean of a low poly world. I have used a cloner to create some ships that sail around the surface of the world, following a spline that's mapped onto the surface of the water sphere. I'm trying to get the ships to leave a 'wake' in the water...

I tried to achieve this by adding a displacement deformer to the water sphere, then limiting that displacement to a field. I then added that field to the ship model – it's in a shape that will leave the impression of the ship disturbing the water as it passes through it, leaving a short trail of displacement behind it.

This ship model with the effector is then cloned, and the clones are set to follow the spline that wraps around the surface of the water sphere. I can see the cloned ships moving around the water sphere and each one has a field, but the displacement deformer doesn't 'see' the cloned fields, it only responds to the field on the original ship object that's being cloned.

Video explaining the problem within the project here:
https://vimeo.com/842835894/5bd1f613af

Looking for advice on whether there's any way to make the deformer 'see' the cloned fields, and if not is there another way that I can make these ships deform the water sphere to create a 'wake' effect?